# react-native expo error: Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'RNAlarmNotification.scheduleAlarm')

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to use a notification package (react-native-alarm-notification) in my React Native project, but am running into some issues. After installing, trying to run scheduleAlarm() results in the following error:

[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating  'RNAlarmNotification.scheduleAlarm')].

I'm not entirely certain what the issue is, as the 'required' parameters of scheduleAlarm are filled and I am uncertain as to what null object is throwing an error. Attempting to fill every possible parameter in scheduleAlarm still returns with null, as does giving only an alarm date and assuming default values are assigned. Tracing the error location however shows the error coming from the regenerator-runtime and react-native modules that came from the default React project build, not from the notification package.

Does anyone have a solution to the problem?

**Function.js:**

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native';

import ReactNativeAN from 'react-native-alarm-notification';


export default function ShowTasks() {

  async function alarmTest(){
    console.log("Alarm test start");

    const fireDate = ReactNativeAN.parseDate(new Date(Date.now() + 10000));
    
    const alarmNotifData = {
      title: "My Notification Title",
      message: "My Notification Message",
      channel: "my_channel_id",
      small_icon: "../icon.png",
      scheduleType:"once",

      data: { foo: "bar" },
      fire_date:fireDate,
    };

    const alarm = await ReactNativeAN.scheduleAlarm({...alarmNotifData});

    console.log("Alarm test finish");
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Button onPress={() => {alarmTest();}} 
        title= 'Click here to test alarm.'>
      </Button>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  
  );
}
```

Comment: Seems to be problem with your linking for the package. You have followed the required steps?

Comment: Error seemed to be that the react-native build was done with expo. Package does not throw this error when built with react-native, which suggests that expo's package linking caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Rebuilding the App solved my issue:

```
npx react-native run-android
```

For android, the package will be linked automatically on the build.
but if it doesn't then You need to link it manually.

Make following changes:

android/app/src/main/java//MainApplication.java

```
add import com.emekalites.react.alarm.notification.ANPackage; on the imports section
add packages.add(new ANPackage()); in List<ReactPackage> getPackages();
```

android/app/build.gradle

```
add implementation project(':react-native-alarm-notification') in the dependencies block
```

android/settings.gradle

add:

```
include ':react-native-alarm-notification'
project(':react-native-alarm-notification').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-alarm-notification/android')
```

Checkout the documentation [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-alarm-notification)